# subtraction 1 from number 00011 == 00010 as int

Tags: objective-c

i am working on simple subtraction having numbers 00011 comes from DB..

i have to subtract 1 from the numbers

00011 - 1  ==> result should be 00010.

00011 numbers comes as string so i convert it in to int  but result i am getting is 10. not getting 00010.

```
long iTemp = [[dicfromDB valueForKey:@"NextNumber"] intValue] - 1;
           = 11 - 1; 
     iTemp = 10;
```

is there a way to keep number as it is like 00011 and subtract number as whole in objective c?

Please note : Leading zeros are not constant. it can be any number of zeros...

so even if i do [NSSString stringWithFormat : @"%.5ld", iTemp] it will give me 3 zero, but when no. of zeros are more or less this equation will fail...

please help...

Comment: Arithmetically `00010` and `10` is the same, leading zeros are never be  displayed in an integer representation. You need to convert the value back to a string representation `[NSSString stringWithFormat : @"%.5ld", iTemp]`. By the way, `intValue` does not match `long`. What is expected after another subtraction of 1? `00009` or `00001`?

Comment: yes i does [NSSString stringWithFormat : @"%.5ld", iTemp] but zeroes are not same ...some tome number will be 0010 or 0000010.

Comment: what equation will fail? Are you trying to compare string? If yes then you should compare numbers, there is no sense to compare strings, because format could be different for the same number

Comment: formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 5;   this will always give me constant string with 5 digit... what if number is 0011 or 00000011.  when i will subtract 1 from int that is 11-1 it will give me 10.  but i wanted 0010 or 00000010.  i want leading zeros which ever i got from DB.

Comment: Consider to use a more reasonable format in your DB.

Comment: no can't be its complicated numbers comping from DB.depend on different Client Setting. but there is no need to as Silmaril already answered it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers `00010` and `10` are equal. `000` prefix  is just a part of visual representation.

If you want keep `000` prefix for the UI or backend then you can use NSNumberFormatter. Moreover it is better to use it for conversion not only from number to string, but from string to number as well (make it global/static/part of class).
Example

```
NSString *sTemp = [dicfromDB valueForKey:@"NextNumber"]; // "00010"
long iTemp = sTemp.intValue; // 10

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = sTemp.length; 

[formatter stringFromNumber:@(iTemp)]; // "00010"
```

P.S. I'd suggest using foundation types (with `NS` prefix) instead of `C` types e.g. long, int...

Comment: so even if i do [NSSString stringWithFormat : @"%.5ld", iTemp] it will give me 3 zero, but when no. of zeros are more or less this equation will fail...

Comment: in my example 3 zeros is not a constant. `minimumIntegerDigits = 5` just tells that number should always be at least 5  digits long inserting zeros at the beginning.

Comment: hm, just get it. Are you saying that `[dicfromDB valueForKey:@"NextNumber"]` could contain string with different digits number? `NSNumberFormatter` will parse it anyway

Comment: hi, thx for your help. can you please make one edit we can have any number of leading zero only i am passing length of string i am receiving from DB... like [dicfromDB valueForKey:@"NextNumber"] i am receiving from DB so  formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = [ [dicfromDB valueForKey:@"NextNumber"]  length];  this ensures any numbers of leading zeros...it giving me correct values...

Comment: please edit i will mark it as correct... thx for your quick help.